# Histogram of sums using groupby (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have a data frame of transactions that contains a customer ID and gross amount spent.

I was able to see how much each unique customer has spent over their lifetime by using

```
merged_df.gross.groupby(merged_df['customer_id']).sum()
```

I would like to create a histoplot to see how many customers have spent xx amount of dollars, but I am unsure of how to do this. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
lifetime_rev_histo = merged_df.gross.groupby(merged_df['customer_id']).sum().plot.hist
lifetime_rev_histo
```

Comment: Please include an example df and the error you get

Answer (score 0):

Try adding as_index = False in the groupby, so that you have a **new df with the customer_id and the gross sum like columns**, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "customer": [1,2,3,4,2,1,3,1],
    "gross": [10,20,10,15,20,15,30,40]
    } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
# Here is where you add the as_index=False
df_grouped = df.groupby("customer", as_index=False).agg({"gross": sum})
```

Then you can use any plotting library, with plotly you would use something like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df_grouped, x="customer", y="gross")
fig.show()
```

Hope it helps